# Show widget at the center bottom on a gridview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a gridview with 2/3 columns and I would like to show a loading indicator at the bottom-center of the grid when the user scrolls to the end. Adding the loading indicator as the last element of the grid doesn't look good because it isn't centered. Is this possible?

Code snippet:

```
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 480 / 315),
  controller: controller,
  itemCount: videos.length + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == videos.length) {
      //show loading indicator at last index
      return SpinKitThreeBounce(
               color: Colors.white,
               size: 35.0,
            );
    }
    return VideoItem(video: videos[index]);
  },
);
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: it is possible, but share your code which help community to understand how you are approaching it and how it can be solved.

Comment: off course it is possible. what you tried so far? posting source code that all defined in one single main.dart would be great for any one to help you easily.

Comment: Question updated with code snippet of how I construct the grid.

Comment: You could use `SliverGrid` wrapped in `CustomScrollView` and adding the loader as footer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should also be possible using `CustomScrollView`.

[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEJTN.png)

Inside this you can use both `SliverGrid` and `SliverList` to create your Layout.
This way you can put the spinner in the `SliverList` and hide it when the `SliverGrid` is updated.

[image]

The yellow oval is the spinner.

this is the code i used:

```
return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverGrid(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        ),
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Product(
                  product_name: listItem[index]['name'],
                  product_pic: listItem[index]['pic'],
                  product_price: listItem[index]['price'],
                  product_old: listItem[index]['old_price'],
                  );
                },
          childCount: listItem.length
        )
      ),
      SliverList(

        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    size: 60.0,

                  );
                },
                childCount: 1,

        ),
      )
    ],
);
```

You can after implement different solutions for the spinner behaviour.

Comment: nice timing haha, I just commented that

Comment: such a great solution buddy, THANK YOU!!